# Не видно карту в Yandex Картах под цветными объектами

Tags: yandex-maps-api, карты, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-maps-embed

Есть в городе около 200 вышек сотовой связи. Метки расставлены в конструкторе карт Яндекс. Оттуда я экспортирую файл со всеми координатами и потом наношу их на карту на сайте. Наношу с помощью объекта `Circle`, который имеет цвет (думаю неважно, но красный), прозрачность (10), радиус (4 км). При приближении зумом объекты накладываются один на другой и получается, что за ними уже ничего не видно. Как можно обойти данную ситуацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теоретически Вы можете оставить метки внутри кругов для обозначения положения вышек. Тогда эти точки можно [кластеризовать](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_create) и, как только метки собрались в кластер, перерисовывать круг вокруг метки кластера. Но тут скорее зависит от задачи карты и того, что Вы хотите на ней увидеть.

В качестве альтернативы можно ограничить минимальный и максимальный зум, чтобы нельзя было перейти к масштабу, где ничего не разобрать. Или же выбрать другой вид визуализации.

Comment: Дело было давно) 
Да , в итоге пришел к тому, что необходимо ограничить зум. 
Другая визуализация, к сожалению, никому не нравилась)